# Bash counting with GREP

Tags: bash

I am trying to find if the word in the file.
If the word is found, it will print 'Found'. 
Else 'Not Found'.

But in the process of trying I am confused by the word count of bash.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash

a=`grep -c -w $1 /file.txt`
if [ $a > 0 ]
then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not Found
fi
```

Comment: Instead of `-c` option use `-q` option of `grep`

Comment: On a side note, congratulations, you just created a text file named `0`, because of `[  ... > ... ]`

Comment: annubhava I tried it still not working.

Comment: When comparing numeric values with the `[` (aka `test`) command, use the Fortran-inspired `-gt`, `-ge`, `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le` operators.  You can only use `=` and `!=` to test strings.  `>` and `<` are redirections; so is `>=` (writing to a file `=`) and `<=` (reading from a file `=`).  Or use the Bash-specific `[[ … ]]` operator.  It has different parsing rules and supports `>`, `<`. etc.  Bash allows `==` as well as `=` for equality; POSIX shells are not required to do so.  Note that arithmetic is all integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
if grep -q -w "$1" /file.txt; then
```

From `man grep`:

> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred. However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.

Comment: I used `grep`'s exit code for `if`. You tried to use `grep`'s possibility to count. In this case use `(( "$a" > 0 ))` or `[[ "$a" -gt 0 ]]` (**g**reater **t**han, see `help test`). `[ $a > 0 ]` creates a file named `0` with content of variable a.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, in place of `text` give your text which are looking into Input_fie, where Input_file is your actual file where you are looking.

```
if grep -q "text" Input_file
then
    echo "text found."
else
    echo "Text NOT found"
fi
```